# Python: Adding boundary values in while loops

Tags: python

As the question says. I'm trying to get 4 'practical' grades from a student, while keeping the boundaries of each grade within 0-40. However i keep getting an error with my following code:

```
while True:
    try:
        mark = int(input("What was your first mark out of the four? "))
        if mark < 0 or mark > 40 :
            print("That is outside the score boundaries. Please try again.")
        else:
            break
    except  ValueError:
        print("That isn't a number!")

counter = 1
while counter <4:
    while True:
        try:
            mark += int(input("And the next mark? "))
            if mark < 0-mark or mark > 40+mark :
                print("That is outside the score boundaries. Please enter the final three marks again.")
            else:
                break
        except  ValueError:
            print("That isn't a number! Please enter the final three marks again.")
    counter += 1

while True:
    try:
        end_mark = int(input("What was your end of year mark? "))
        if end_mark < 0 or end_mark > 60 :
            print("That is outside the score boundaries. Please try again.")
        else:
            break
    except  ValueError:
        print("That isn't a number!")


#calculations
average = mark/counter
total_score = average + end_mark

#processing
if total_score > 50:
    if end_mark < 30:
        print("You pass conditionally with %{}. Your practical mark was averaged at {}, but your end of year mark was only {}.".format(total_score, average, end_mark))
    else:
        print("You pass with %{}. Your practical mark was averaged at {}, and your end of year mark was {}.".format(total_score, average, end_mark))
else:
    print("Im sorry. You failed the year with %{}. Your practical mark averaged at {}, and the end of year mark was {}.".format(total_score, average, end_mark))

print("End of Code")
```

How may i fix this?

Comment: What's the error ?

Comment: "if mark < 0-mark or mark > 40+mark :" (the second paragraph of code).

Comment: If i enter, for example, 54, it'll accept the number when im trying to set the boundary at 40.

Comment: `mark < 0 - mark` => `mark < 0` and `mark > 40 + mark` => `False`. What should that condition mean?

Comment: Note: in pytrhon, you can use the nicer writing of this condition : `if not (0 <= mark <= 40):`, which more visually express your boundaries.

Comment: Use separate variables for input, and name the sum variable `mark_sum`. Don't complicate...

Comment: IM wanting to add three more mark scores in that while loop without it giving the error "That is outside the boundary". It thinks the second time im inputting the score it's totalling to the number outside the boundary.

Comment: @LogicStuff the exam question want's the variables added together to prove i can use a while loop in this context. It is part of the assessment. I need to be able to set boundaries in this loop to imagine the boundaries are for each individual input... confusing, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're first adding and then checking and therefor `mark` will never be `> 40+mark` or `< 0-mark`.

```
mark += int(input("And the next mark? "))
# The next line is where the problem is
if mark < 0-mark or mark > 40+mark : # mark will never be > 40+mark or less than 0-mark 
    print("That is outside the score boundaries. Please enter the final three marks again.")
else:
    break
```

Do this instead.

```
tmp = int(input("And the next mark? "))
    if not (0 <= mark <= 40):
        print("That is outside the score boundaries. Please enter the final three marks again.")
    else:
        mark += tmp
        break
```

Comment: Thankyou im finding that easier to understand BUT, what does the 'tmp' stand for?

Comment: `tmp` is just a temporary variable to store the input value until we check that it is in range. Mark it as the answer if this helped you.